# How to have a multi dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm setting up my borrowing transaction in my project, and I need to have a multi dropdown.

If the button + is pressed then another dropdown added. Where should I set the code for my dropdown?

thanks...

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
    <label for="colFormLabel" class="col-sm col-form-label">tool</label>
    <select name= "tools" class="form-control" id="colFormLabel"required>
        <option value="">crimper</option>
        <option value="">soldering iron</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1.2 mb-3">
    <label for="colFormLabel" class="col-sm col-form-label">quantity</label>
    <select name="qty" class="form-control" id="colFormLabel"required>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 mb-3">
    <label for="colFormLabel" class="col-sm col-form-label">more</label>
    <button id="plus" class="plus form-control btn-outline-success" name="+" ><b>+</b></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#plus").click(function () {
    var $tools = $("select[toolname$='tools']:first").clone();
    $("form").append("<br/>").append($tools);
  });
});
```

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask])

Comment: you need some jquery help here to achieve this.

Comment: You have 2 dropdown in your code. Which dropdown you want to be added dynamically on click of plus button? Do you want both dropdown or only one to be added dynamically?

Comment: Please note that your select have the same id `colFormLabel` an ID should always be unique

Comment: yes I need  both dropdowns to be added dynamically @Yogendrasinh

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen ok

Comment: If you want to add another dropdown dynamically, what keeps you from writing the code for that? Where does the data for that dropdown come from?

Comment: that is just a sample code from bootstrap, I only want to know how to do it with the other languages @NicoHaase

Comment: What do you mean by "other languages"? Still, what have you tried so far to achieve what you are looking for? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I tried to used jquery but when I pressed the + button it performs a space, I'm not actually expert at this @NicoHaase

Comment: So, why not share that code? It's not a shame to start programming and not know everything from the first minute, but to reproduce and fix your problem, we need to see where you took the wrong steps

Comment: ok, thank you, just a minute  @NicoHaase

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="myDiv">
            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                <label for="colFormLabel" class="col-sm col-form-label">tool</label>
                <select name= "tools[]" class="form-control" id="colFormLabel"required>
                    <option value="">crimper</option>
                    <option value="">soldering iron</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1.2 mb-3">
                <label for="colFormLabel" class="col-sm col-form-label">quantity</label>
                <select name="qty[]" class="form-control" id="colFormLabel"required>
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 mb-3">
            <label for="colFormLabel" class="col-sm col-form-label">more</label>
            <button class="plus form-control btn-outline-success" name="+" ><b>+</b></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script>
    $(".plus").click(function() {
        var html = $(".myDiv").html();
        document.body.insertAdjacentHTML( 'afterbegin', html );
        //alert(html);
    });
</script>
```

And this is another way you can call a particular function using `onClick` :

**html**

```
<button class="plus form-control btn-outline-success" name="+" onclick="myDiv()"><b>+</b></button>
```

**JS:**

```
function myDiv() {
      document.body.insertAdjacentHTML( 'afterbegin', '<div>...</div>' );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I removed the id's in your html. Since when you clone you can not clone the id because they need to be unique.

Also I guess you just want to duplicate the complete row? So changed your code to do that. You didn't have any select with the `toolname` attribute so that doesn't work. Also you didn't had a form to append to so added that to the html.

I added square brackets (`[]`) to the name of the select elements so they can be used as array data.

Last I told the clone method to include the event handler on the button as well so it work's on all rows but setting the `withDataAndEvents` parameter to true. Alternatively you can use event delegation for that.

Added a little bit of CSS so the row actually showed as a row in the snippet. Of course this is not needed for the code to work.

I recommend to use `on('click', fn)` instead of `click()` but it works fine with click as well.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#plus").click(function() {
    var $row = $(".row:first").clone(true);
    $("form").append($row);
  });
});
```

```css
.mb-3 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
      <label for="colFormLabel" class="col-sm col-form-label">tool</label>
      <select name="tools[]" class="form-control" required>
        <option value="">crimper</option>
        <option value="">soldering iron</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1.2 mb-3">
      <label for="colFormLabel" class="col-sm col-form-label">quantity</label>
      <select name="qty[]" class="form-control" required>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 mb-3">
      <label for="colFormLabel" class="col-sm col-form-label">more</label>
      <button id="plus" class="plus form-control btn-outline-success" name="+"><b>+</b></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: @daphnieandam, Your welcome, if this or any other answer answers your question then please accept the answer you like so others can see that you don't need help anymore.